# Google Form Information and Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to modify a Google sheet that is populated by a Google form. It is a form for returns and includes quantities and prices for up to 5 returns at once (there is a separate section for each of the 5). What I need to do is multiply the quantity by the price for each section and then total the value of the return per response. Can someone please explain to me how to do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided and example showing how your data is organized.  Without that it is difficult to provide any formula.

Comment: @Hamza-Safdar please do not use AI to edit content.  Also please do not edit content unnecessarily. This question's language is clear what is missing is sample data and example results.

Comment: Jeannie, please do not reapply tags that have been removed.  If you'd like to improve your question see my comment from the 14th.

Answer (score 0):

Choose **Insert > Sheet** and copy form responses to the new sheet with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) like this:

```
={ 'Form Responses 1'!A1:N }
```

You can then use plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas in the new sheet to multiply and sum the values in the rows.

Alternatively, use an array formula to process all rows in one go.

See [sumproduct()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294).